# Iteration over json array elements in PostgreSQL

Tags: arrays, json, postgresql

I've got two JSON data row from the column in postgresql database and that looks like this.

```
{
  "details":[{"to":"0:00:00","from":"00:00:12"}]
}

{
  "details":[ 
             {"to":"13:01:11","from":"13:00:12"}, 
             {"to":"00:00:12","from":"13:02:11"}
            ]
}
```

I want to iterate over details and get only the "from" key values using a query in postgresql.
I want it like

```
                             from
                           00:00:12
                           13:00:12
                           13:02:11
```

Comment: The data-type of the column is jsonb or json?

Comment: yes, the datatype of a column is jsonb

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `jsonb_array_elements`

```
select j->>'from' as "from" from t 
cross join jsonb_array_elements(s->'details') as j;
```

[**Demo**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=76dd3893034d347cebc77578c614207c)

Comment: The above details are from two columns and I need to fetch all other columns like id using the key "from".
from time range between 13:00:00 and 13:03:00.

Comment: @rakesh : This answers your original question, please consider asking a new one with the additional details